# How can I access a method's parameter from an associated attribute?

Tags: .net, vb.net, attributes, custom-attributes

Given the following classes, how can i intercept Class1.SampleMethod's Value from SampleAttribute?
Thanks

```
Public Class Class1
    <SampleAttribute()> _
    Public Function SampleMethod(ByVal Value As Integer) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class

<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)> _
Public Class SampleAttribute
    Inherits System.Attribute

    Private _Value As Integer

    Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

---

EDIT:

Given Andrew Hare's answer, maybe I'm trying to use the wrong construct. I have a long list of similar methods and i need to execute a set of operations every time one of them is called. I thought that attaching an attribute to each of them would be the most straight-forward solution. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to model cross-cutting behavior (unrelated objects need to do similar/same things) then AOP is the way to go.  I've used PostSharp to great effect, both compile and run-time weaving.  It will basically inject code at compile (or run-) time into the compiled assemblies which will call your methods based on your definition.

**Update**
RE: PostSharp: There are dozens of good tutorials out there on [codeplex](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ps-custom-attributes-1.aspx).  You'll need to build a new attribute that inherits from PostSharp.Laos.OnMethodBoundaryAspect.  Overriding the methods from that base class will tell the post-compiler what code to insert during compilation.  That tracing example on codeplex should show you everything you need to do.
**EndUpdate**

Another architectural pattern you might want to look at is [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (e.g. [a quick google found this msdn article)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998543.aspx).

If those methods are actually object behavior in some related classes, then an observer could be notified of activity, then respond accordingly.  The disadvantage of a publish-subscribe pattern like this is you need to register your list of dependents with the observer.  If you just have a bunch of methods on classes, then the concept still somewhat holds true but isn't necessarily ideal.

Of course, the poor man/woman's approach is to just add a line of code at the end of all the methods ;-)

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Can you provide an example of how could I accomplish my task with PostSharp? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

It sounds like you are trying to do something via [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).  Perhaps something like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) would be helpful - it would allow you to do what you want via attributes.

---

Given the types you posted try something like this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection

Class Program
    Private Shared Sub Main()
        Dim type As Type = GetType(Class1)
        Dim members As MemberInfo() = type.GetMembers()
       
        For Each member As MemberInfo In members
            Dim attributes As Object() = member.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(SampleAttribute), True)
           
            If attributes.Length > 0 Then
                ' this means that the current "member"
                ' has your custom attribute
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```